# Ituens in app purchase Product status is "Ready to Submit" but "Submit for Review" button is disable

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I want to submit in-app purchase Product on itunes which is currently in "Ready to Submit" status but "Submit for Review" button is disable.
We had created in-app purchase product once and application was submitted but due to in-app purchase product,application was rejected.
Now,We have new versions of both the application and in-app purchase product which needs to be submitted.How can I submit both application and in-app purchase product on itunes connect.
Help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Does iTunes connect report your new in app purchase as ready for review or still "rejected" ? If your in app purchase shows "rejected", edit the in app purchase description (put a space or something at the end) and then save the in app purchase again, it should take it out of reject state from memory.

Comment: In app purchase product is in "Ready to Submit" state as mentioned in my question.I have submitted app and then rejected immediately before few days.So my app status shows me rejected and in app purchase shows me Ready to Submit.

Comment: Hi Zhang, What can I do next to resolve this?

Comment: Try adding a space at the end of your app's description (not the in app purchase description, the app description). See if that takes it out of reject state.

Comment: Thanks Zhang.I have question that can we submit in-app purchase separately without app binary or need to submit along with app binary?

Comment: Um, I'm not too sure sorry. I've ever only submitted 1 in app purchase.

Comment: Finally i could submit my new in-app purchase with latest version of the Binary.When I submitted my binary in-app purchase also submitted.